# how to use an application resource in user control xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a app.xml with some resources in it such as:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <con:EnumToVisibilityConverter x:Key="EnumToVisibilityConverter" />
    <con:NegateBoolConverter x:Key="NegateBoolConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="BaseStyle">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="DatePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">

    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label"  BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">

    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,2,2,5" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

I want to use them in my user control xaml as follow:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="App.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

Since my user control xaml is in View directory, the above mentione syntax is not accepted by system and complained that it can not find view/app.xaml. How can I add path to the Source so it can find it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do that. Application resources are available all over the app, so all you need to do is either this in xaml:

```
Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"
```

Or this in C# (inside your control's code):

```
Style baseStyle = (Style)this.FindResource("BaseStyle");
```

Comment: The styles works, but not the converter. Is there any way to do the same things as style with converter?

Comment: I don't see why the converter wouldn't work. You just have to do it the same way.